# Unable to locate an element on twitter LoginPage in appium

Tags: java, twitter, appium, android-uiautomator

[image: Twitter Login Page via appium desktop]

I am trying to locate "Log In" on twitter loginpage using appium, but i see "Have an account already?Log In" is clubbed under one locator and as expected this locator is not accepting "tap" operation of appium desktop as well.

Therefore, I'm not unable to automate twitter logIn operation in appium.

Can someone please advise how to do the same?

Comment: Please add DOM structure in the question to give us more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If `Tap by coordinates` is working in Appium Inspector on the element (not just regular tap, which selects an element, but tap by coordinates, which taps the absolute location) then you can use that solution to tap `Log in` text.

First, we want to locate the element, then move by a small `x` axis offset (about 20px) over to the 'Log In' link.

Depending on the language you are using, you can use `TouchActions` class to accomplish this:

```
// get the web element for link
IWebElement logInLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@text, 'Log in')]"));

// get the x,y coordinates for the link
int xCoordinate = logInLink.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.X;
int yCoordinate = logInLink.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.Y;

// perform action that moves to coordinates, and taps 20 pixels to the right
new TouchAction(driver).MoveTo(xCoordinate + 20, yCoordinate).Press().Release().Perform();
```

You will probably have to play around with the offset value `+ 20` here and try out `10`, `30`, etc. You can also get the coordinates location using 'Tap by coordinates' in Appium inspector, and then debug your code to get the coordinates of the WebElement, and adjust your offset to make the x coordinate of the element match the x coordinate of the desired tap location.